# Check if the user has access to post login pages in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

In Zend Framework whats a better method to restrict user from accessing post login pages
if the user is not logged in.Without Zend I would have write a code to check if the
userid is set in session or not and put that code in common file(being used on all post
login pages).

In Zend Framework I can check that using hasIdentity method of zend_auth but I don't
want to check that inside all actions.The another method I am thinking is to create a
plugin and hook it to routeshutdown event,then after fetching controller and action
name from request object I can decide whether to redirect user or not.

Please suggest some good method to implement it in zend framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would normally write a Controller Plugin and add it to the front controller. This way you can intercept the dispatch and route process where you want and issue a redirect to an appropriate page.

```
class Your_Controller_Plugin_Authcheck extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
}
```

In the Bootstrap class:

```
protected function _initFrontControllerPlugins()
{
    $this->bootstrap(array('AuthcheckPlugin', 'FrontController'));

    $front = $this->getResource('FrontController');
    $front->registerPlugin($this->getResource('AuthcheckPlugin'));
}

protected function _initAuthcheckPlugin()
{
    $plugin = new Your_Controller_Plugin_Authcheck();

    return $plugin;
}
```

BTW: This is Zend Framework 1 - might work the same in 2, but I believe you might change things a bit there if you already use it.